# React Native Button onPress firing twice on iOS device, but not on Android

Tags: react-native, button, onpress

My console output shows the following when I press the button in my app on an iOS device:

2019-09-22 13:45:25.116 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] You tapped the button

2019-09-22 13:45:25.116323-0400 AwesomeProject[5368:2651835] You tapped the button

I am logging 'You tapped the button' to the console inside the onPressButton function and it is getting called twice for each button press.

Here is my complete App.js file which is an exact copy from: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

export default class ButtonBasics extends Component {
  _onPressButton() {
    console.log('You tapped the button once!')
    alert('You tapped the button!')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
           <Button
             onPress={this._onPressButton}
             title="Press Me"
            />
         </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
             onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="Press Me"
            color="#841584"
           />
         </View>
        <View style={styles.alternativeLayoutButtonContainer}>
           <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="This looks great!"
           />
           <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="OK!"
            color="#841584"
           />
        </View>
       </View>
     );
   }
}

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
     margin: 20
   },
   alternativeLayoutButtonContainer: {
    margin: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
   }
 });
```

I am really at a loss why onPressButton is firing twice on iOS but not on Android.

Comment: Your onPressButton function is defined inside the actual component you're trying to use it in but outside of the component you're calling it as a prop. This could be triggering strange behavior. Why don't you define `onPressButton` in the parent component and pass it as a prop?

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I am just learning React Native and was following the example provided by Facebook shown here:  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches  I am a little confused by your suggestion.  Can you provide an example of what you meant?

Comment: I can't help without the full code because it's not clear what's actually going on. The example link is totally fine though. Is there any reason you can't match it exactly? I would say update your initial post with the full source of the view currently mounted on your screen and its child components.

Comment: Entire App.js added as requested.  This is an exact copy from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches.  The only thing I added is the concole.log line.  Still firing twice on iOS and only once on android.

Answer (score 2):

Try with an arrow function

Example:-

```
onPress = {() => this.onPressButton()} //in Button

onPressButton = () => {                //onPressButton function
 console.log('You tapped the button');
}
```

Comment: This is how function binding works without constructor

Comment: Yes, one of the features of ES6.

Comment: Not sure of this syntax.  The code I listed is the example code given by facebook.

Comment: Have you implemented it or not? With arrow function.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with his code it comes straight from the react native website.

Answer (score 1):

https://snack.expo.io/r1OTvkEdS

If you take a look at the snack, you will see that it's neither logging nor alerting twice. It's possible the **the javascript bundler** is logging separately from the emulator. That's why on the first log you see the stamp [tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] but on the other log you see a different stamp. It's two separate interfaces logging the same thing. What are you using to view logs? You should be either using your terminal or a react debugging tool.

TLDR: It's not firing twice, it's just two separate loggers doing the same job.